# Which one is grammatically correct?

Tags: tenses

a. I didn't realize that you were a cop.
or
b. I didn't realized that you were a cop.

Comment: Ask at *English Language and Learners* (ell.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Please use titles that relate to the content in some way.  This will help other people search for the same question in the future.

Comment: Please never just ask “Which is correct?”  It shows no effort on your part, and gives us nothing to go on.  As [the Help Center says in its “How to ask a good question” section](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask):  **“Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!”** Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) is definitely correct.

"realized" is the past tense of "to realize".

I did not **notice** that you...
I did not **see** that you...
I did not **realize** that you...
I did not **forget** that you...

Try changing the words highlighted in **bold** to the past tense and see if they make sense to you.

Answer (score 1):

When two (or more) verbs come one after the other like this in English, the second verb must be an infinitive ("to notice" or "notice") or a participle ("noticing", "noticed"). Only the first verb is conjugated.

So:

- I didn't **notice**
- I am **noticing**
- I hadn't **noticed**
- I don't **like | eating** vegetables
- I have **stopped | trying | to understand**

Comment: This rule seems terribly wrong or at least vastly oversimplified. I can say things like this sentence where a verb is followed by a verb without it being  the infinitive or the participle. The hinge of course is the *like this* you place there. Can you spell it out?